# Is there any way of set samesite cookies in Rundeck to None?

Tags: iframe, configuration, session-cookies, rundeck, samesite

I don´t know if the application called Rundeck can set the parameter of Samesite Cookies to None, in order to access from an iframe to the application.

Comment: Maybe increasing the cookie session time? https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#session-timeout

Comment: But I want login to my Rundeck from a iframe, and, in order to do this, it is necessary to set the parameter SameSite of the cookies to None.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that isn't available yet, you can suggest that [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).